# How to convert an enum value to a compressed string?

Tags: c#, enums, compression

I have an enum that is defined like:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0,

    ValueOne                = 1 << 0,
    ValueTwo                = 1 << 1,
    ValueThree              = 1 << 2,
    ValueFour               = 1 << 3,
    ...
    ValueTwoEightyOne           = 1 << 280,
}
```

I would like to be able to convert usage to the shortest string possible, similar to:

```
var compressedString = ConvertToCompressedString(MyEnum.ValueOne | MyEnum.ValueThree | MyEnum.ValueFour);
```

And then in a different part of the program, I would like to convert the compressedString back to the enum

```
var enumValue = ConvertBack(compressedString);
```

What is an efficient method to convert an enum with so many values? If there is a better way of handling this type of use case, I'm interested.

Comment: `ValueTwoEightyOne           = 1 << 280`? Are you sure you are OK with this and every other overflow over `<< 32`?

Comment: Yep, that's a pretty hefty number. Even with `enum MyEnum : long`, expect the unexpected past 64

Comment: When you say "compressed string", do you literally mean System.String? Or do you just mean the combined flag value (as a MyEnum with the respective bits set)? The combined flag value you already have, you don't need the conversion method, just OR them together. The enum is just a normal integer with lipstick on it (which is why can't have 1 << 280 as it will overflow).

Comment: `1 << 1 == 1 << 33 == 1 << 65`... etc...

Comment: I'm still in the planning/exploring stages for this feature in my program and thought that I may run into an overflow problem going this route.  I ultimately wasn't sure if an enum, that didn't explicitly inherit from int or long, had limits.  Guess it's back to the drawing board...

Comment: Have you looked at the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class?

Comment: @Oded I wasn't aware of that and it looks like AndersForsgren provided a nice solution of what I want to do, using a BitArray

Answer (score 2):

`enum` values are backed by an integer field in memory. So what more compression you need than the integer itself?

```
MyEnum value = MyEnum.ValueOne | MyEnum.ValueThree | MyEnum.ValueFour;
int i = (int)value;
// transport i
```

But be careful because 1 << 280 (2^280) is a pretty large number that cannot be stored in an `Int32` or even `Int64`.

Comment: Not to mention that with a backing `Int32` this would overflow pretty quickly... Maximum of 32 values for a flags enumeration.

Comment: @JimGeurts, what's for sure is that with enums the biggest number you could store is long.MaxValue. So depending on your exact requirements there might be other more adapted structures.

Comment: @darin Any suggestions for how to accomplish something similar without using an enum?

Comment: @JimGeurts, what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Ultimately something similar to how filters are implemented for stack exchange api v2 (http://kevinmontrose.com/2012/01/11/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-implementing-filters/). I have a lot of fields that may or may not be included with a response and I wanted to short, concise way specifying those.  I can open up a different question or bring it to chat, if that would make more sense

Answer (score 1):

If I needed a "Flags enum" with more than 64 flags, I'd probably use an enum for only the bit indices, and then wrap a BitArray inside a class to hold the values.

To get the compact representation, you can convert the bit array to a byte array. I omitted that step from the code, but you can do e.g. [like this](http://geekswithblogs.net/dbrown/archive/2009/04/05/convert-a-bitarray-to-byte-in-c.aspx) (pay attention to the endianness!)

```
public class LargeFlagsEnum<T> where T : struct
{
   private BitArray bits;

   public LargeFlagsEnum(int numBits)
   {
      if (!(typeof(T).IsEnum))
        throw new ArgumentException("Expected enum type");
      bits = new BitArray(numBits);
   }

   public byte[] GetBytes()
   {
      return bits.ConvertToByteArray();
   }

   public void Set(T flag, bool value)
   {
      bits[Convert.ToInt32(flag)] = value;
   }

   public bool Get(T flag)
   {
      return bits[Convert.ToInt32(flag)];
   }    
}

// Example:

enum MyFlags
{
   First = 1,
   SomethingElse = 280,    
}

class Example
{
   void Main()
   {
      var someFlags = new LargeFlagsEnum<MyFlags>(281);
      someFlags.Set(MyFlags.SomethingElse, true);
      Transmit(someFlags.GetBytes()); 
   }
}
```